# Google Map control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to create a control in silver light like below:

Address on left and google map location on right side.

Address

Arora towers, pune -->>> Google map location of the address.
411018

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but wouldn't it be better to use the [Bing Maps Control](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2949) if Silverlight is a requirement?